# Broadcast variables in parfor loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

The following loop results in an error in `C_mat` and `B_mat`:

```matlab
%previously defined
N_RIPETIZIONI=2;
K=201;
parfor n=1:N_RIPETIZIONI*K 
    [r,k]=ind2sub([N_RIPETIZIONI,K],n);
    B=B_mat{r};
    C=C_mat{r};
end
```

The warning says:

> The entire array or structure B_mat is a broadcast variable. This might result in unnecessary communication overhead.

The same for `C_mat`.
How can I fix it so that the indices of `B_mat` and `C_mat` are no more broadcast variables?

Comment: Note that  you can use `parallel.pool.Constant` to copy the arrays to all workers before the loop. This will avoid sending the same data repeatedly. You can also do `parpool('Treads')` to make your parallel code use threads instead of worker processes, which avoids copying the constant arrays altogether. Threads share memory, processes need to send data back and fourth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the way you index `B_mat` (i.e. not using `n`), every thread in the `parfor` requires the entirety of `B_mat` to run. The big bottleneck in parfor code is transferring copies of the data to each node.

MATLAB is basically telling you that if you were to do this, you may actually have slower code than otherwise. Its not that `B_mat` is some type of variable called "broadcast", its that the way you wrote the code, each `n` in parfor requires a copy of `B_mat`.

I assume this is not your real code, so we can't really help you fix it, but hopefully this explains it.

Comment: I see but I thought that [r,k]=ind2sub([N_RIPETIZIONI,K],n); helped avoid broadcasting right? I mean this is indexed to n.

Comment: @Lusian "broadcasting" means sending the same data to all workers. Just like a radio or TV program is broadcast, everyone receives the same program on their device.